# Mysql: How to create a new database based on dump file?

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql dump file and wanted to create a new database with the data from this dump file. To this end, on the Mysql command line I entered: `mysql –u[root] –p[test1234] new_name < c:\dump.sql;`

But the command line just shows a new `->` line (I think it expects additional parameters?). How can I make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this to work,new_name empty database must be created first and then try running :

mysql –u  root  –p  new_name  <  "C:\dump.sql"

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql> mysql -u root -p
mysql> enter password
mysql> use database;
mysql> SOURCE C:\\dump.sql;
```

make sure you have admin rights.